# Pyspark freeze in client mode with Yarn Cluster Manager

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Following theses instructions: https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/install-configure-run-spark-on-top-of-hadoop-yarn-cluster/ i set up a 3 node cluster and am able to run spark-shell. But when i try to run pyspark i got theses messages:

```
hadoop@master:~$ pyspark 
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/02/15 21:51:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/15 21:51:06 WARN util.Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
19/02/15 21:51:12 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
```

and the screen freeze (there is no other messages).
I have no idea how i could solve this issue.

PS: As explained in the link i first deployed a 3 node hadoop-yarn cluster and then installed spark on the master Node (after launching yarn-start.sh.